# Textchange event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am doing a preview of what I am currently typing in a web page using ASP.NET. What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I type or change text in the textbox, the `<h3>` or `label` element will also change and always copy what the `textbox` value is without refreshing the browser. Unfortunately I cannot make it work. Here is what I tried.

.ASPX

```
    <div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
    <div class="Padding10px">
        <h1 class="Margin0px">Preview</h1>
        <hr />
        <p></p>
        <h3 id="NewsTitlePreview" class="TextAlignCenter" runat="server">Title</h3>
        <h5 id="NewsContentPreview" class="TextIndent50px TextAlignJustify" runat="server">Content</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
    Title
    <asp:TextBox ID="Titletxt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Titletxt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    Content
    <asp:TextBox ID="Contenttxt" runat="server" onchange="Contenttxt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</div>
```

.CS

```
protected void Titletxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewsTitlePreview.InnerText = Titletxt.Text;
}
protected void Contenttxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewsContentPreview.InnerText = Contenttxt.Text;
}
```

I Tried Adding Autopostback = true... but it only works and refreshes the page and i need to press tab or enter or leave the textbox :(

UPDATE: I Tried This - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237279/dynamically-updating-label-text-on-textbox-changes) But Still Doesnt Work :(

Comment: Do the _TextChanged events fire at all? If you put a breakpoint in them, does it reach the code when you change the text?

Comment: Have you tried javascript? It's so much easier to implement these type of functionality on client side.

Comment: actually it fires when i put autopostback = "true" and when i refresh... what i'am trying to achieve is for it to work without leaving the textbox and not refreshing :(

Comment: Add ScriptManager Control and use label inside an update panel. Don't forget AutoPostBack property.

Comment: i will try :) thanks for the help

Comment: how exactly do i make the scriptmanager work? i added script manager then update panel.. i placed the textboxes in the content template... but still no progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this script function in your code and in body write onload and call that function.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startProgram() {
       setTimeout('errorcheck()', 2000);

    }

    function errorcheck() {
        setTimeout('errorcheck()', 2000);
        document.getElementById("NewsTitlePreview").innerText = document.getElementById("Titletxt").value
        document.getElementById("NewsContentPreview").innerText = document.getElementById("Contenttxt").value
    }
</script>


<body onload="startProgram();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

  <div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
 <div class="Padding10px">
<h1 class="Margin0px">Preview</h1>
<hr />
<p></p>
<h3 id="NewsTitlePreview" class="TextAlignCenter" runat="server">Title</h3>
<h5 id="NewsContentPreview" class="TextIndent50px TextAlignJustify" runat="server">Content</h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
Title
<asp:TextBox ID="Titletxt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
Content
<asp:TextBox ID="Contenttxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  />
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: i will try :) please wait :) im excited for this to work :)

Comment: it only works when i leave the textbox... i need it to work without leaving textbox... or on every keypress

Comment: It works :) If you want text come faster when you enter a character, change that 2000 to 1000 :)

Comment: i tried :( it doesnt work :( i dont need to leave the textbox.. the code you gave me only works when i leave the textbox

Comment: did to add this.<body onload="startProgram();">

Comment: i did.. PS: this is a content page.. so the <body> is on the masterpage and also the JS

Comment: I didn write not even a single line in .cs page.

Comment: then why didnt you remove the ontextchange codes :(

Comment: and the autopostback also.. :(

Comment: FINALLY IT WORKED!!! i found the PROBLEM!!! i needed to add "ContentPlaceHolder1_" on the ID's in the javascript -_- since they are in content page of masterpage :)

Comment: thanks :) but i got one last problem with this code... well when i reach the last part of the content.. it doesnt WRAP :( i just goes on and on to the RIGHT of page :( how do i fix that? thats the last obstacle till this one is complete

Comment: okey bro :) i fixed the problem with text wrap :) a little css trick :) thanks :) its now complete :) i love you guys!!! Thanks To ALL THAT HELPED!

Comment: if you have used css page write overflow :hidden

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your analysis of the behavior of the control (it only fires the event when you leave the control), even when you have `AutoPostBack="True"`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c(v=vs.85).aspx) says it all:

> The TextBox Web server control **does not raise an event each time the user enters a keystroke, only when the user leaves the control**. You can have the TextBox control raise client-side events that you handle in client script, which can be useful for responding to individual keystrokes.

So you either have to be satisfied with the current behavior, or set up some client side event handling to do some validation, etc. client side.

Comment: thanks for the insight :) iam currently trying to implement update panel to make it work... but im still having no luck in making it work xD

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. The event is still raised after leaving the control.

Comment: yeah :( do you have any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Yes, use [`onchange` or `onkeydown`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/574941/993547) in javascript.

Comment: just edited my post :( i tried the "Dynamically updating label text on textbox changes?" that is exactly what i plan to achieve but doesnt work :(

Comment: it's really nice :) thats kinda what i need.. but i outputs/copies the textbox into the label character by character.. how do i do that without jquery? plain javascript or some asp.net tricks?

Comment: Why not use jQuery? It is quite easy to use and will probably help you out on other occasions. Even ASP.NET uses it nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Download and include JQuery library. And also modify title and content textbox so they don't change their Id's

Title
        `<asp:TextBox ID="Titletxt" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Content
            `<asp:TextBox ID="Contenttxt"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Then add this script and it will work.

```
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Titletxt').on('input', function () {
            $("#NewsTitlePreview").text($(this).val());

        });
        $("#Contenttxt").on('input',function () {
            $("#NewsContentPreview").text($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work this how change event call using jquery dont forget to add google apis

```
   <script>

    $('#txtbox').change(function() {
        alert("change Event");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: i already tried that :( unfortunately it doesnt work the way i need it :( it only works on refresh :( i need it to work everytime i change the text :( for example: when i type a word, it copies the value of the textbox per every letter and one by one

Comment: Then try javascript it will work fine...or try keypress event for textbox then it will work fine...selectindex work when you write something and then leave the textbox then it will hit event....java script will do the trick for you

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how to do it with javascript bro? :) i would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I have added some code for you may this helps solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One of the best idea... 
Just change your code to this. it works

ASPX

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<ContentTemplate>
  <div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
  <div class="Padding10px">
    <h1 class="Margin0px">Preview</h1>
    <hr />
    <p></p>
    <h3 id="NewsTitlePreview" class="TextAlignCenter" runat="server">Title</h3>
    <h5 id="NewsContentPreview" class="TextIndent50px TextAlignJustify" runat="server">Content</h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Width960px MarginLeftAuto MarginRightAuto MarginTop10px">
Title
<asp:TextBox ID="Titletxt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Titletxt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
Content
<asp:TextBox ID="Contenttxt" runat="server" onchange="Contenttxt_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</div>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.CS

```
 protected void Titletxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
NewsTitlePreview.InnerText = Titletxt.Text;
UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
protected void Contenttxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
NewsContentPreview.InnerText = Contenttxt.Text;
UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Comment: i tried it :( doesnt work :( doesnt it need a keypress trigger or something? i only works when i leave the textbox :( i need it to work everytime i enter a character